# Crontab stopped working, crons are being called but not executed

Tags: cron, centos6

It was working with no issues few months ago, and I can't remember any changes since then. /var/log/cron and Logwatch report both indicate that the scripts are being called, but actually nothing is executed.

- I am using full paths of php & cURL, and commands work correctly when I just insert them into SSH.
- crond service is running
- username doesn't exist on `cron.deny` file, only 'nobody' is there.

My crontab:

```
root@server [~]# crontab -l -u my-username
SHELL="/sbin/nologin"
MAILTO=""
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-username/public_html/cron.php
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path &>/dev/null
*/4 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://full-path
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://full-path
0 */12 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-username/public_html/path/to/script.php
```

Logs:

```
root@server [~]# tail -15 /var/log/cron
Jul 23 05:18:03 de CROND[18188]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path &>/dev/null)
Jul 23 05:18:03 de CROND[18189]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path)
Jul 23 05:18:03 de CROND[18190]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-username/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 23 05:19:02 de CROND[18328]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 23 05:19:02 de CROND[18327]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-username/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18479]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-username/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18472]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18477]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18474]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/maldetect/maldet --mkpubpaths >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18473]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18476]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/bin/curl http://full-path)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18478]: (my-username) CMD (/usr/bin/curl http://full-path)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18475]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18480]: (cacti) CMD (php /home/cacti/public_html/cacti/poller.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 23 05:20:02 de CROND[18481]: (root) CMD (LANG=C LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg --lock-file /var/lock/mrtg/mrtg_l --confcache-file /var/lib/mrtg/mrtg.ok)
root@server [~]#
```

What else should I check?
Running CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is only telling you that it tried to run the job, not the exit status.

In terms of what else you can do to help debug cron: Set cron's log level way up with `-L 15`. You can set this in `/etc/defaults/cron`, with line `EXTRA_OPTS='-L 15'`. Then restart - `sudo service cron restart`. Your logs will now show something like this on errors:

```
Jul 23 11:45:01 localhost CRON[3565]: (CRON) error (grandchild #3566 failed with exit status 127)
```

Beyond that:

- That `SHELL="/sbin/nologin"` looks suspect. Does that work? Try removing it.
- Setting `MAILTO` to your local mail box `MAILTO=dave` (or just unsetting it from empty string) and checking your mail, or just piping the output of your scripts to a log, might also help debug the situation.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much for your help. It worked only after removing that suspicious line (which I don't know what does it do/mean). Cron is working fine now! Should I make mailto string empty again? Or is there better logging output than spamming my email? Thanks again @s-pinkus

Comment: No probs :). Upto what you want to do with MAILTO. It can get very noisy if your script output a lot of junk, so a lot of people disable it. But it can be useful for debuggin or if your scripts only output when something is wrong. Generally using `syslog` is better though.

Comment: I ran into another issue. cURL seems to be fetching old/cached copy of the page. The script usually takes ~3min to finish, but now curl is showing output immediately, which is an old attempt. This is happening also outside cron, when I execute curl in SSH, but on browser it's running properly. Any suggestion?

Comment: Probably best to raise as a fresh question.